# How to fix infinite loading of view-source after using Angular Universal?

Tags: angular, adsense, angular-universal, server-side-rendering, view-source

I am currently trying to instaure Google Adsense on the website http://sightmess.com . It was made with Angular, that is why I used Angular Universal in order to display the HTML view-source and hopefuly be accepted by Google Adsense bot.

The website is working 100%, however I can only see the view-source of the first page (http://sightmess.com). For example when I am on http://sightmess.com/home  and if I try to display the view source code (CTRL+U) begins an infinity loading.

The problem doesn't come from the host because even if I try to do it in local it doesn't work.

I think the problem comes from the size of the javascript files. There is no back, that means that you can remove your internet connexion when the first page is loaded. Maybe the problem comes from here, I have no idea ....

Thank you very much for your help.

P.S: I tryed to propose the website to Google Adsense but they still report that there is "No Content", I think by displaying the view source of the second page (and the other one) they will accept the website.

Hugo

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong. It is because my website was linked with firebase, and I don't understand why but i wasn't able to load the view code using angular universal.